# Enable auditing in ArangoDB using Spring

Tags: spring-boot, arangodb, auditing

How can I enable auditing in *ArangoDB* using Spring in order to use **@CreatedDate** and **@LastModifiedDate** annotation?

For example, using *MongoDB* you must add **@EnableMongoAuditing** likes

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;

@EnableMongoAuditing 
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

If there isn't any possibility to use Spring, is possible enable the auditing in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data ArangoDB does not support auditing. Auditing in the DB itself is available in the Enterprise Edition. [See here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/Manual/Administration/Auditing/).